Wrong type infer for react-hook-form and zod
I have a code like this:
const scheme = z.object({
  date: z
    .string()
    .transform((value) => value)
    .pipe(z.coerce.date()),
})

const useForm = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues>(options: {
    scheme: z.Schema<TFieldValues>
}) => {
    const { scheme } = options
    
    return useRHForm<TFieldValues>({
        resolver: zodResolver(scheme),
    })
}

useForm({
    scheme, // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
})

Why is this happening and how to fix that?
Playground

What is FieldValues?

A type FieldValues from "react-hook-form"

Zod doesn’t automatically infer that the transform or pipe will change the final type to Date. The solution is to ensure the schema correctly maps the type to Date.
const scheme = z.object({
  date: z.coerce.date(), // Coerce string to Date
});

const useForm = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues>(options: {
  scheme: z.Schema<TFieldValues>
}) => {
  const { scheme } = options;
  
  return useRHForm<TFieldValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(scheme),
  });
};

useForm({
  scheme, // No type error
});

Or transform with
const scheme = z.object({
date: z
.string()
.transform((value) => {
  // Example transformation: trimming input
  return value.trim();
})
.transform((value) => {
  // Coerce the transformed string to a Date object
  const coercedDate = new Date(value);
  
  // Check if the result is a valid Date
  if (isNaN(coercedDate.getTime())) {
    throw new Error('Invalid date');
  }
  return coercedDate;
    }),
});


Yeah that could work but I need to transform the input so I can't just specify z.coerce.date

I just updated my answer with the transform you mentioned

Same error in playground with your code https://tsplay.dev/WGQB9N
